# Why is typescript object in false branch possibly undefined?

Tags: typescript

I have the following typescript code, in which obj is definitely *not* undefined within the outer "if" (and thus also within the inner "if"), and yet the typescript 3.4.5 compiler gives me a warning:

```js
let obj: {'x': number} | undefined
obj = Math.random() > 0.5 ? {x: 1} : undefined
if (obj) {
  if (false) {
    obj['x'] += 1 # "obj is possibly undefined" here: huh?
  }
}
```

If I replace the inner "if" with `if (true)` it doesn't give a warning. Is this a typescript bug or something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That's likely because a condition of `false` has exhausted any code branches that inference could use; you don't have a valid scope anymore. If my conjecture is right, it's not exactly a bug; "fixing" it would require the compiler pretending it's still in the last valid branch for no good reason. My recommendation is to use `allowUnreachableCode` set to `false`, in which case the unreachable code itself would give a warning. Unless you have some other use case in which inference break that is not clear by this example.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow all the details of what you're saying because I don't know how the compiler traverses the AST, but at least it would seem the compiler should ignore the whole `if (false)` branch and not give a false warning about types in that branch. In my real code the `false` comes from a global option which turns off some functionality, so adding `allowUnreachableCode` as you suggest would only cause many incorrect warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend letting the compiler in on the secret that `false` is actually coming from a global boolean option... by writing `if (globalOption)` and not `if (false)`.  But maybe there's some kind of pre-build step which replaces your global option with the `false` literal or something?  Not sure I see the use case here.

Anyway, if you want to force the compiler to entertain that `false` might actually be `true`, you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to widen `false` to the `boolean` type:

```
let obj: {'x': number} | undefined
obj = Math.random() > 0.5 ? {x: 1} : undefined
if (obj) {
  if (false as boolean) { // assertion widening
    obj['x'] += 1  // no error
  }
}
```

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/DYUwLgBA9gRgVgLggbwOQA9VIHYFcC2MIATgL4QA+Eu2AJiAGYCW2ItAULHBALwQCyAQzAALAHTFBdKPgAUASggA+CAAYxAVggB+FOiQBGckhr1mrDkwYRZXRcnYQIVmw0HAAziAiCPEGFBQoFL2jk7Q8ADaGKgAuhAA1HwGEGGk7KRAA)

That will stop the compiler from giving up on the control flow anaylsis and prevents the error. Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Wow, that works -- as does replacing literal `false` with `option` where `const option: boolean = false`! So weird that the compiler can't figure it out in the literal case, but the other (where it's literally the same, haha) it has no trouble with.

Comment: I come from a C/C++ world where there could be no conceivable difference between a literal and a const of the same type & value... still figuring out this JS/TS world!